# CakePHP Automagic Form Elements - datetime 24

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

In my form I want to have the time in 24h mode. In **datetime** specification in the cookbook there is a parameter **timeFormat** that accepts **12**, **24** or **null** values but when I try to add it inside the parameters of the form input it doesn't work. Still I have the 12h mode with am/pm select. The **dateFormat** works OK.

My view is:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Reservation.arrival', array(
            'label'=>'Check IN', 
            'div'=>'clear IconDate',
            'timeFormat ' => '24',//doesn't work
            'dateFormat' => 'DMY',
            'minYear' => date('Y') - 0,
            'maxYear' => date('Y') + 1 ,
            )
        );
```

I am using CakePHP 1.3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a space in your key 'timeFormat '. Make sure you remove the trailing space at the end, and it should work just fine. :)

Before:

```
'timeFormat ' => '24'
```

After:

```
'timeFormat' => '24'
```

Comment: when I posted the comment there was still a time limit to accept :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $this->Form->input('tob',array('selected'=>'06:35:00','label'=>'Time Of birth','type'=>'time','timeFormat'=>'24' ));
```

This way selected value can be set.
'selected' attribute is there so set default time in select boxes